# How to make a transparent part of a div

Tags: html, css, z-index, background-color, transparent

Im trying to make part of a div transparent so the transparent part can show the background pattern ( a complicated one made with css).
So i have a view_main div and 2 other small divs , divs that will be transparent and show the background

```css
#View_main{
 margin-left:7%;
 top: 15%;
 height:100%;
 width:70%;
 background-color:white;
 position:relative;
 border:0;
 z-index:1;
}
```

the `left_space` div

```css
#left_space{
 height:12%;
 width:12%;
 background-color:transparent;
 margin: auto;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0; left: -100%; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}
```

the `right_space` div

```css
#right_space{
 height:12%;
 width:12%;
 background-color:red;
 margin: auto;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: -100%;
}
```

i have tried to make the left_space with z-index=2 and the view_main z-index=1 and still nothing ,
[Here is a simple example](http://jsfiddle.net/5BZdF/1/), i im trying to show the background (in this case is green but in my code is a pattern ,or image) from the left_space div 
I have also tried the opacity but still nothing!
 does someone have any idea?

here it is a visual rapresentation 
[image]

Comment: Why don't just set the same background pattern to left_space div? Or try looking into CSS mask property http://thenittygritty.co/css-masking

Comment: approach you followed is too complicated instead you can remove unnecesary div and portion part you want to make transparent is little difficult.

Comment: @Teo Dragovic because the background is like a grid and if i made the left space with the same bacground the pattern will not show correctly ,also im trying to make my code css only with no image :/

Comment: @Shaib Chikate i cant understand you , what do you mean remove unnecessary div?

Comment: @p3rand0r Are space div's necessary for some content or are you just trying to get blue shape? If you're just using div's for styling you can accomplish same thing with pseudo-classes. Here's example: http://codepen.io/teodragovic/pen/KhgeJ

Comment: Strange enough i cannot replicate your code in my web page nor i jsfiddle :/ http://jsfiddle.net/5BZdF/4/

Comment: Sorry, I was using SASS by default. Here's compiled code: http://jsfiddle.net/5BZdF/5/

Comment: @Teo Dragovic yes sir :) that's pretty much what i wanted to create :D, please post it as a answer so i can chose it as the best one :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's code for creating blue shape using `before` and `after` pseudo-classes

```
body {
  background-color: green;
}

.container {
  margin: 50px auto;
  height: 300px;
  width: 210px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
}
.container:before, .container:after {
  content: "";
  height: 44%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: blue;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 112%;
  left: -6%;
}
.container:before {
  top: 0;
}
.container:after {
  bottom: 0;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5BZdF/5/)**

Answer (score 0):

Use opacity property in the div that you want to make transparent and set its value from 0.1 to 1

[Reference Link on w3cschools](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_image_transparency.asp)

From your above diagram and link to code provide by you
I modified your code to get that structure:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<style>
  body{
    background-color:green;
  }
  #View_main{
    margin-left:7%;
    top: 15%;
    height:300px;
    width:210px;
    background-color:blue;
    position:relative;
    border:0;

}

#left_space{
    height:12%;
    width:12%;

    background-color:green;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: -88%; bottom: 0; right: 0;
    opacity:1;
}


 </style>
 <body>

 <body><div id="View_main">


 <div id="left_space"></div>
 </div>
 </body>

  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Use opacity:0.1 which will give you transparent background and you have use 1 which is no transparent value

Comment: You have added opacity:0.1 to div which you want to see and to div you want to be transparent. Check you code once again. Its working for me bro. #right_space{ opacity:0.1}

Comment: can you please show me the code? i cant seem to do it by myself i have tried to add the opacity to all the single divs but still nothing , i cant see the green background from my left_space div :(

Comment: no this doesnt show me my background, maybe you didnt understand me , or i didnt make my self clear , i need to make left_space completely transparent and show the green background and make a "hole" in the blue div in my case view_main :/

Comment: I m still not understanding you tell me which color you want to make it transparent...dont say the div just say me the color.

Comment: its not that simple , http://i.cubeupload.com/lTgTgg.png this is what im trying to do

Answer (score 0):

I can refer you,

That the `#right_space` you can give green color

http://jsfiddle.net/5BZdF/3/

Check this

Comment: Thank you for your reply , but the main porpoise of that jsfiddle link was to show the main idea , the background is not green in my original code , its a picture or a pattern , so i cant make the right_space green as the background behind it its a picture :/

Answer (score 0):

You can use a transparent box with a large `box-shadow` drawn with `:before` or `:after` pseudo elements.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="View_main"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#View_main {
  position:relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height:300px;
  width:210px;
}

#View_main:before {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1000px blue;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -40px;
  content: '';
  height: 80px; /* Change width and height to increase or decrease transparent box area */
  width: 20px;
  opacity: 1;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
}
```

```css
body{
  background-color:green;
}

#View_main {
  position:relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-left:7%;
  height:300px;
  width:210px;
  border:0;
  top: 15%;
}

#View_main:before {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1000px blue;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -40px;
  content: '';
  height: 80px;
  width: 20px;
  opacity: 1;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="View_main"></div>
</body>
```